# Populating SelectList with sobject

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, force.com, multi-select

I am trying to create a class that will populate the a multi selectlist depending on what URL parameters are passed in.

Im having trouble. The slectlist never renders, however, looking through the debugger, i can see that records are found and that it should populate.

Am I missing something stupid?

VisualForce.Page

```
<apex:page controller="PopUp">

<apex:form >
    <apex:selectList value="{!objectType}"  multiselect="true">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!SelectListOptions}"/>
    </apex:selectList>
</apex:form>
```

Controller class:

```
public with sharing class PopUp {

public sObject objParameter {get;set;}
public string fldParameter {get;set;}
public string queryType {get;set;}
public static string objName{get;set;}
public list<SelectOption> selectListOptions {get;set;}
public static list<string> TEST {get;set;}
public String[] objectType= new String[]{};

public PopUp(){

    objName = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('obj');
    sObject dynObject = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objName).newSObject() ; 
    objParameter = dynObject;

    fldParameter = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('fld');
    String queryType = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('qt');

    system.debug('***objParameter: ' + objParameter);
    system.debug('***fldParameter: ' + fldParameter);

    //List<selectOption> L =  getPicklistValues(objParameter, fldParameter, queryType);
}

public static list<SelectOption> getPicklistValues(SObject obj, String fld, String queryType)
{
    list<SelectOption> options = new list<SelectOption>();

    if(queryType == 'soql'){

        string query = 'select ' + fld + ' from ' +  objName;
        system.debug('***query: ' + query);

        List<sObject> dynList = Database.query(query);
        system.debug('***dynList: ' + dynList);

        for(integer i=0;i< dynList.size();i++){

            string fldValue = string.valueof(dynList[i].get(fld));
            system.debug('***fldValue: ' + fldValue);

            options.add(new SelectOption(fldValue,fldValue));
            TEST.add(fldValue);
        }
    }

    system.debug('***options: ' + options);
    return options;

}

public List<selectOption> getSelectListOptions() {
    return getPicklistValues(objParameter, fldParameter, queryType);
}

public String[] getObjectType() 
{
    return objectType;
}

public void setObjectType(String[] objectType) 
{
    this.objectType= objectType;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusing the VF page by having essentially two getter methods (the one you added, and the one you told the controller to create itself by specifying `get;` in the variable declaration):

```
public list<SelectOption> selectListOptions {get;set;}

public List<selectOption> getSelectListOptions() {
    return getPicklistValues(objParameter, fldParameter, queryType);
}
```

It doesn't look like you're populating `selectListOptions` anywhere, so the VF page sees that and doesn't add any options to your picklist. The VF page will only call `getSelectListOptions()` if it doesn't find a getter for your variable, so modify the `selectListOptions` declaration like so, and you should be fine:

```
public List<SelectOption> selectListOptions {set;}
```

In fact, it doesn't look like your page should have access to set this, so you could remove the setter as well if you wanted.